# Activity in the backstack recreated when rotated

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation, back-stack

I am working on an application with most of my activities locked to portrait orientation. I have a single activity which supports rotation, so when the app undergoes a configuration change in the rotatable activity, activities in the backstack are also recreated, can I restrict only the activity on top to be recreated?

```
  <activity
        android:name=".ui.image_gallery.ImageGalleryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
```

Comment: What's the issue with recreating backstack activities? Are you perhaps incorrectly storing `saveState`?

Comment: I want to retain the activity state of all activities in backstack, that is the expected behaviour as those activities do not support rotation, right?

Comment: Activities can be destroyed and recreated even in backstack depending on device memory, that's why even rotation-less activities should properly store `saveState`. To see if your app behaves correctly You can toggle on "don't keep activities" in developer options of your test device.